# Show next date if meets criteria or other cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to get a formulae to show me the next available date in a list.  Essentially, what is today's date, look at the list and show me the next available date.  At the moment I am using the below formulae which if using the table below it would output 01-Jan-14

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ATW!$L$4:$L$19>TODAY(),ATW!$L$4:$L$19),1),MAX(ATW!$L$4:$L$19))

Column L             M       N       O
01-Jan-13           YES      NO     NO
01-Jan-14           N/A     N/A     N/A
```

What I need to do though is adjust that formulae so it checks for the next available date, however it will return the last date in Column L where either Column M, N, or O has 'No' in it.

So above, it would show 01-Jan-13 as the date.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If 1/1/14 had a NO, would that be preferable to 1/1/13 as it is in the future? Or in other words: do you simply look for the last date in your list where any "NO" appears - independent of today's date - or does today'S date also have any role here?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a date when there's at least one "No" in that row perhaps try this adjusted version

`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ATW!$L$4:$L$19>TODAY(),IF(ATW!$M$4:$O$19="No",ATW!$L$4:$L$19)),1),MAX(IF(ATW!$M$4:$O$19="No",ATW!$L$4:$L$19)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Given comments below perhaps should be this version

`=IFERROR(IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ATW!$L$4:$L$19>TODAY(),IF(ATW!$M$4:$O$19="No",ATW!$L$4:$L$19)),1),LARGE(IF(ATW!$M$4:$O$19="No",ATW!$L$4:$L$19),1)),MAX(ATW!$L$4:$L$19))`

Comment: Thanks, this works however has a slight error.  Using the table in my first post.  If Jan 13 has all "Yes", and the Jan 14 has "N/A" as above, it outputs the date as 00/01/1900 instead of 01-Jan-14

Comment: So ideally you want the first date after today with "No" in the row......if there isn't such a date you just want the latest date with "No" ....and if there are no dates with "No" what then, just the latest date? Is there any difference between "Yes" and "N/A" that would be relevant here?

Comment: Thats correct yep.  It's basically looking at an invoicing table.  So if it is Yes then it means its completed fully.  They're set to N/A for dates in the future which I don't need to worry about yet